# xCode does random stuff while debugging

Tags: xcode, debugging, random

I was debugging some code, and noticed that xCode does some random stuff:

1) There is an `if` block that I'm absolutely sure my program should not be entering, but it does, for some reason.

2) When I place a breakpoint inside that `if` block, the execution stops right there (as expected), but then if I use the "step over" button, the program goes back and forth, and then enters in the next `else if` block.

Code:

```
    if(self.position.x > 1.0 * firstPage * kAdvance)
        power = (self.position.x - firstPage * kAdvance) / 20.0;
    else if(self.position.x < 1.0 * lastPage * kAdvance)
        power = (self.position.x + lastPage * kAdvance) / 20.0;`
```

(firstPage, lastPage and kAdvance are `int`)

What can be wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Code please so we can help....

Comment: I thought it could be just an xCode problem.

Comment: Is this all in a for loop? Which line is the breakpoint exactly?

Comment: @Diego so you are saying that if you set a break point on line 2 and step over it goes back to line 1 and then to line 3... then into line 4?

Comment: It goes from line 2 to to 1, then 2, then 1, then 3 and 4... or something like that. It is not in a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Rofl, the problem was really stupid:

I was playing with my schemes a couple of days ago, and had set everything to "release."

My bad. I set Analyze, Test and Run back to debug and now it works properly.